# Draw an ellipsoid

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to draw an ellipsoid.Any idea how to do it? 
The picture should look like this (I don't care about color or mesh lines, but I do want coordinators looks the same).The function is x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1

[image]

Comment: (1)parameterize the sphere using sine-cosine (2)`surf` (3)`axis equal`.

Comment: Doesn't work, I tried, it only draw 2 surfaces, not a closed shape

Comment: This is a sphere

Comment: Can you show me how to do it?? or you want to see what I have first?

Comment: @user3390471... You have to tag the one who want to see your comment. Otherwise he may be not see it. (A MWE is almost always helpful)

Comment: @koleygr oh, sorry, still new to stackexchange...... i’m Very new to pgfplot, I only used it for once, so if you can show me how to do it, it will be great!

Comment: I think you'll find section 3 here: http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb38-3/tb120duck.pdf useful.

Comment: @CarLaTex Well, thanks, but it doesn't apply me...... This is for School, normally I would try to figure things out.... But the group paper is due in a couple of days, I was sick absent from the school the day when everybody's roll is assigned....Because I have some graphic design background and some javascript knowledge, everybody just automatically assigned me all the graphs without even asking me... in a week, I had to do 40 graphs according to requirements, I figured out a lot of them, but still, I've never done any latex graphing before, you want me to figure out all 40 graphs in a week

Comment: @user3390471 An MWE is _always_ useful, at least to see what `\documentclass` you are using. You don't need to do everything by yourself (otherwise it's useless to ask), but just a starting point we can use to reply.

Comment: @CarLaTeX It's impossible....You have no right to judge people.... Especially you don't even know what is the situation, what's going on.... There are plenty of ppl on this site, who had no idea to do the thing, but being forced on the hand.... No friends know about the topic, try to figure things out by themselves, but not enough time....Got totally no choice, so that come here to post a post as the last resolution, hope someone can help......

Comment: @user3390471 I'm not judging you, keep calm! I'm just saying that everybody, even if in a hurry, can add something like `\documentclass[border=3.14pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}` This gives us many information: the documentclass you are using and the packages you loaded.

Comment: @CarLaTeX I actually don't find LaTex is that useful, I had my hands on it because of a math class, and it is pretty....And being a graphic designer, I do like pretty things... But up until now, I never needed to graph anything, so I never learned or even looked about graphing..... But just for regular documents math edits, I can't say I'm good, but at least I haven't need to ask any help to do anything yet.....It is only the graphing gave me huge headach... I know I'm a graphic designer, graphing should be fun for me.....but rushing 40 graphs in a week with no knowledge graphing in Latex.....

Comment: @user3390471 TikZ ("TikZ ist kein Zeichenprogramm")=TikZ is not a drawing tool, neither is LaTeX. Do you know you could create your images with other tools and include them in a LaTeX document with `\includegraphics`?

Comment: @CarLaTeX Ok. I literally asked 3 posts in like a couple hours, and I'm also in a school, to be honest, the first 2 posts, I posted all the codes I found, linked the sources where I found, give them credit...and asked what I need in detail, but the third post, this one, I was so exhausted, juggling from class, homework due.....By the time I posted this post, I was sooo not function properly...... Ask Marmot, he/she literally answered my posts back to back, and all perfect.....That's why I was so happy after he/she answered me again.......

Comment: @CarLaTex Yeah....I know!!! I major in graphic design, I have tons of drawing tools that I paid for... Illustrator, paintbrush, sketch.....etc.....etc....And I like drawing by hand much better, that's why I always got away with 2D graphs, I always draw by hand, and \includegraphics to the math homework......But this semester, the most graphs I'm dealing with is 3D, 3D is pretty hard to draw by hand, especially when it needs to be precise.....Past semesters, I'm always the only one who does all the graphs, but that's ok....2D graphs is very easy to draw in my design software, but this semester

Comment: @CarLaTex so first time ever, I actually found LaTex draw graph is easier, especially for function plots, gets basically layout down, just need to change function, and another graph done......Marmot is really really really big help, he/she got my 2 types of function graph down, I probably can knock out at least 10 graphs with that 2 layout...... I did 10 graphs last weekends, and so half can be done by tomorrow, then I only need about 20 more, I may still need to ask massive amount of questions to get those done......

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73783/discussion-between-user3390471-and-carlatex).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example. I was not sure whether you wanted to have some shading and/or opacity, so I included both as it is easier to turn it off than on.

```
\documentclass[border=3.14pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[view={135}{20},%colormap/blackwhite,
axis lines=center, axis on top,ticks=none,
set layers=default,axis equal,
xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}, zlabel={$z$},
xlabel style={anchor=south east},
ylabel style={anchor=south west},
zlabel style={anchor=south west},
enlargelimits,
tick align=inside,
domain=0:2.00,
samples=20, 
z buffer=sort,
]
\addplot3 [surf,opacity=0.4,domain=-1:0,
domain y=0:360] ({sin(y)*sqrt(1-x^2)},{2*cos(y)*sqrt(1-x^2)},{x});
\addplot3 [surf,opacity=0.4,domain=0:1,
domain y=0:360,on layer=axis foreground] ({sin(y)*sqrt(1-x^2)},{2*cos(y)*sqrt(1-x^2)},{x});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Really just for fun, an attempt to produce something close to your screenshot.

```
\documentclass[border=3.14pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[view={135}{20},colormap={blue}{
            color=(blue) color=(blue)
        },
axis lines=center,axis on top,
ticks=none,set layers=default,axis equal,
xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}, zlabel={$z$},
xlabel style={anchor=south east},
ylabel style={anchor=south west},
zlabel style={anchor=south west},
enlargelimits,
tick align=inside,
domain=0:2.00,
samples=20, 
z buffer=sort,
]
\addplot3 [surf,draw=blue!30,fill=white,domain=-1:1,samples=20,
domain y=00:180] ({x},{-2*cos(y)*sqrt(1-x^2)},{-sin(y)*sqrt(1-x^2)});
\addplot3 [surf,draw=blue!30,fill=white,domain=-1:1,
domain y=0:180,on layer=axis foreground] ({x},{2*cos(y)*sqrt(1-x^2)},{sin(y)*sqrt(1-x^2)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A perhaps better version. But I do not understand why I have cheat here as well, i.e. why I have to adjust the coordinates `(y1)` and `(z1)` by hand.

```
\documentclass[border=3.14pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
%\pgfsetlayers{pre main,main,axis foregound}
\begin{axis}
[view={135}{20},colormap={blue}{
            color=(cyan) color=(cyan)
        },axis lines=none,axis equal,set layers=standard,
enlargelimits,domain=0:2,samples=20, z buffer=sort,
]

\pgfonlayer{axis background}
\draw[-] (axis cs:0,0,-1.5)--(axis cs:0,0,-1);
\draw[-] (axis cs:0,-3,0)--(axis cs:0,-2,0);
\draw[-] (axis cs:-2,0,0)--(axis cs:-1,0,0);
\addplot3[draw=none] coordinates{(0,0,-2) (0,0,2)};
\addplot3[draw=none] coordinates{(0,-2.5,0) (0,2.8,0)};
\endpgfonlayer
\pgfonlayer{main}
\addplot3 [surf,draw=cyan,fill=white,domain=0:1,samples=20,
domain y=00:180] ({x},{-2*cos(y)*sqrt(1-x^2)},{-sin(y)*sqrt(1-x^2)});
\addplot3 [surf,draw=cyan,fill=white,domain=0:1,
domain y=0:180,on layer=axis foreground] ({x},{2*cos(y)*sqrt(1-x^2)},{sin(y)*sqrt(1-x^2)});
\coordinate(x1) at (axis cs:1,0,0);
\coordinate(x2) at (axis cs:1.5,0,0);
\coordinate(y1) at (axis cs:0,1.9,0);
\coordinate(y2) at (axis cs:0,2.5,0);
\coordinate(z1) at (axis cs:0,0,0.9);
\coordinate(z2) at (axis cs:0,0,1.5);
\endpgfonlayer
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[->] (x1)--(x2)node[left]{$x$};
\draw[->] (y1)--(y2)node[right]{$y$};
\draw[->] (z1)--(z2)node[right]{$z$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's perfect!!!! I love it!!! you're my god!!!! xD

Comment: I actually like that rainbow color better^^ The blue graph that I screenshot from the textbook actually looks boring......xD

Comment: one more question, is there anyway to make the z-axis longer??? I feel like it looks a bit too short..........

Comment: Yes, but I do not fully understand the question. If you just want to change the height of the plot, you may achieve that by `\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,height=12cm}`. If you want to make the axis higher, you can add an empty plot ` \addplot3 [draw=white,opacity=0.4,domain=-4:4,domain y=0:360] ({0},{0},{x});`. If you want the z-axis to touch the correct spot, replace `\end{axis}\end{tikzpicture}` by `\coordinate (z) at (axis cs:0,0,1);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\draw[-] (z) -- ++(0,0.55cm);}`.

Comment: @marnot Thank you, I actually figured out the color, use cyan instead blue will look more like in the textbook picture.....xD