# How do I translate my ellipsoid, while also scaling it properly?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, shapes, tikz-shape

I have this code for drawing an *ellipsoid*, but I want to be able to translate it so the center is in *(3, 3, 3)*. Right now I'm not sure how, since it seems to be working fine, but as soon as I change the *length*, *width* and *height* the result is weird. This is how it looks with `length=3`, `width=2` and `height=1`:
[image]

This is my code when it's translated but NOT scaled (largely inspired by: [Draw an ellipsoid](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/417491/draw-an-ellipsoid))

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \def\translatex{3}
        \def\translatey{3}
        \def\translatez{3}
        
        \def\length{1}
        \def\width{1}
        \def\height{1}    
    
        \begin{axis} [view={135}{20},colormap/redyellow,
            axis lines=center, axis on top,ticks=none,
            set layers=default,axis equal,
            xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}, zlabel={$z$},
            xlabel style={anchor=south east},
            ylabel style={anchor=south west},
            zlabel style={anchor=south west},
            enlargelimits,
            tick align=inside,
            domain=0:10,
            y domain=0:10,
            samples=20, 
            z buffer=sort,
        ]
        \addplot3 [surf,opacity=0.4,domain=-1:0,
            domain y=0:360] ({\translatex+\length*sin(y)*sqrt(1-x^2)},{\translatey+\width*cos(y)*sqrt(1-x^2)},{\translatez+\height*x});
        \addplot3 [surf,opacity=0.4,domain=0:1,
            domain y=0:360,on layer=axis foreground] ({\translatex+\length*sin(y)*sqrt(1-x^2)},{\translatey+\width*cos(y)*sqrt(1-x^2)},{\translatez+\height*x});
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Tilføj navn 2}
    \label{fig:tilføj_navn_2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Right now it displays this:

[image: Translated but NOT scaled]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what you mean by "weird". The axis is not perfectly crossing at `(0,0,0)`, but I doubt you can see that. To correct it, you need to set e.g. the z-scale.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\translatex}{3}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\translatey}{3}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\translatez}{3}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\length}{3}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\width}{2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\height}{1}    
\begin{axis}[
view={135}{22},
zmin=0, zmax=5,
colormap/redyellow,
axis lines=center, axis on top, axis equal, ticks=none,
xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}, zlabel={$z$},
xlabel style={anchor=south east}, ylabel style={anchor=south west}, zlabel style={anchor=south west},
]
\addplot3[
surf, opacity=0.4, 
domain=-1:1, samples=40,
y domain=0:360, samples y=20,
z buffer=sort,
] ({\translatex+\length*sin(y)*sqrt(1-x^2)},{\translatey+\width*cos(y)*sqrt(1-x^2)},{\translatez+\height*x});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Elipsoid in a 3D graph]

You could choose to draw some help lines

```
\draw[dashed] (3,0,0) -- (3,3,0) (0,3,0) -- (3,3,0) (3,3,0) -- (3,3,3);
```

[image: Elipsoid in a 3D graph and dashed lines]

Or maybe choose the view angle better

```
view={110}{20},
```

[image: Elipsoid in a 3D graph and dashed lines]

Without `opacity` and `axis on top`:

[image: Elipsoid in a 3D graph and dashed lines]